# Gstreamer documentation: gst_my_filter_convert() definition not found

Tags: gstreamer

The function gst_my_filter_convert() is used in the GStreamer Caps Negotiation documentation. But, I could not find the definition there. I'm trying to understand Caps negotiation better and curious as to what the definition of this function might look like? Any explanation in this direction would help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample code in the [GStreamer PluginWriter's Guide](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/advanced/negotiation.html) the function declaration of gst_my_filter_convert() must be

```
GstBuffer * gst_my_filter_convert (GstMyFilter *filter, GstBuffer *buf);
```

This function has nothing to do with caps negotiation anymore.  It is called from the chain function of that filter and as such it is supposed to perform the actual conversion of this hypothetical element that can convert between samplerates.  Is takes `buf` as input and allocates, fills and returns another GstBuffer.  Caps negotiation happens before the chain function is ever called.